# How can I deploy a permission set with connected apps?

Tags: deployment, connected-apps, permission-sets

I am trying to deploy a permission set that has some connected apps assigned. However, after deploying to upper environment the connected apps are missing from Assigned Connected Apps. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).  When asking a question, including a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is helpful. As written, your question does not have enough detail.

Comment: did you also deploy the connectedApp(s)?

Comment: No, the connected apps are not available to be deployed in change sets.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to also deploy your ConnectedApps to the target org.  If, given you are using Changesets (I'm assuming you are not using sfdx) and that metadata type is not available, you have two options:

### Option 1

Manually recreate the connected apps in the target org, then deploy via Changeset the `PermissionSet` and any related objects. Be sure to recreate the `ConnectedApp` exactly, especially the API name.

### Option 2

Use a tool other than Changesets to deploy the `ConnectedApp`.  Vendor tools are great at this (see Gearset, Copado, Flosum, Blue Canvas, etc.)

Alternatively, you can use Workbench to `retrieve`, then `deploy` metadata using a package manifest

For ConnectedApp, prepare a `package.xml` file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>MyConnectedAppDevNameHere</members>
        <name>ConnectedApp</name>
    </types>
    <version>55.0</version>
</Package>
```

Here is where you can find the Metadata retrieve and deploy tools in Workbench

[image]

Then you can deploy the **PermissionSet** and related objects using a Changeset, or, also [deploy using Workbench](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_permissionset.htm?q=permissionset).